# Issue while creating a public link of an assest

Tags: content-hub, content-hub-scripting

We are creating a public link of an asset through an action script whenever an asset is modified.
The format of the public link is `"Content hub domain/CDN name" +  "Rendition name" + "Filename"` which means Public URL is generated based on the filename.

**Note:** If there is already a filename with a  public URL then the second instance of same filename will not be able to generate a public URL, which is fine but in some cases, we had to delete the old image and replace it with the updated correct image, in that case also `Content hub` is giving error while creating a public link.

```
   The specified target is invalid. Exception:
   Stylelabs.Scripting.Exceptions.RuntimeException: The script execution
   failed in runtime - The specified target is invalid. --->
   Stylelabs.M.Sdk.Exceptions.ValidationException: The specified target
   is invalid. Failures: Property: 'RelativeUrl'.: ‘{RelativeUrl}’
   already exists Stack trace: at
   Stylelabs.M.Sdk.ScriptClient.Clients.EntitiesClient.SaveAsync(IEntity
   entity) in
   /src/Stylelabs.M.Sdk.ScriptClient/Clients/EntitiesClient.cs:line 176
   at Submission#0.<CreateForRendition>d__15.MoveNext() in :line 195 ---
   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
   --- at Submission#0.<<Initialize>>d__0.MoveNext() in :line 66 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at
   Stylelabs.Scripting.Engines.CSScript.Persistence.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<<Load>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   in /src/Stylelabs.Scripting/Engines/CSScript/Persistence.cs:line 222
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Stylelabs.Scripting.Script`1.Run(Object
   globalScopeObject) in /src/Stylelabs.Scripting/Script.cs:line 255 ---
   End of inner exception stack trace --- at
   Stylelabs.Scripting.Script`1.Run(Object globalScopeObject) in
   /src/Stylelabs.Scripting/Script.cs:line 259 at
   Stylelabs.M.Base.Scripting.Base.ScriptSubCacheBase.Execute(CachedScript`1
   script, Func`4 scopeHandler, Func`4 resultHandler) in
   /src/Stylelabs.M.Base/Scripting/Base/ScriptSubCacheBase.cs:line 469
```

However, when we try to browse the existing URL, we get a 404 error.
Is there any cache thing in content hub which prevents content hub to create a public link for that asset?

**Update** :  Added error in text format, so that it will be useful for SEO.

Comment: Add this error in text format as well so that it will be useful for SEO.

Comment: Sure Gaurav, i will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We created a sitecore ticket for that and after few conversations we were able to resolve that.

**The issue is caused due to the following:**

When an asset is deleted via the asset details page, it is actually "soft deleted". This means that the asset can still be recovered.
In this case, the asset's public links are not deleted from the system, they are just disabled.

The public link is only deleted after the asset is "hard deleted". You can go to Manage > Trash to see all the assets that are currently "soft deleted".
Items in trash will be permanently deleted after 30 days.

You need to "hard delete" the incorrect asset and then re-upload the file. The script works after "hard deleting" the file.
We have tested this and was able to run the script with success